# Icons missing for some SE sites in "top answers"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Since Careers 2.0 is starting to look pretty good as you've ironed out lots of bugs already (thanks!), it's time to start reporting more cosmetic issues. :-)

English language & usage favicon is missing when I selected a "top answer" from that site.

[image]

(The img points to http://sstatic.net/englishlanguageandusage/Img/favicon.ico, which gives 404.)

I tried some other (new) SE sites too: most seem to work (but I haven't posted to all, so couldn't test), but at least for [**Webapps**](http://sstatic.net/webapplications/Img/favicon.ico) it's also broken.

Edit: Oh, and **meta.so** [icon](http://sstatic.net/metastackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico) is broken! (Heh, I guess it's *possible* that someone would want to highlight a meta contribution in their CV... :P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be good to go now.  Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 1):

[Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) is also broken. It's getting the sstatic.net folder name wrong; the image it's trying to load is `http://sstatic.net/unixandlinux/Img/favicon.ico`, but UL's images are in `unix`; it should be trying to load `http://sstatic.net/unix/Img/favicon.ico`:

[image: The correct icon]